# is it possible to enable WPS to connect to a WiFi using ADB commands?

Tags: wi-fi, adb, android-studio

Is there any way to enable WPS in Android through ADB commands to get to connect to the WiFi?

What I want to do is automatically testing this feature in a router with different types of devices connected, one of them b eing a phone (any) with the latest version of Android (10.0 at the moment I'm writing this).

I'd like to control it through ADB for two reasons:

1. I want to automate it
2. I need to make sure the phone was disconnected and connected again thanks to WPS and not other settings of the phone itself or the router

Maybe I can control the app [Simple WPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.i.akihiro.SimpleWPS&hl=en_US) through ADB commands? However I'm a bit newbie using ADB and I'm not sure how to do that.

I also found the [Wi-Fi Easy Connect](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-easy), but again, not sure how to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, WPS is enabled on at least Nexus 5, LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1). I have connected my Nexus 5 to a Wi-Fi AP using WPS a few times since no one knew the password. So, could you mention the device model and Android version? Also, this is about Android connecting to a Wi-Fi AP, not the other way around (other devices connecting to Android as a mobile hotspot) right? Just to make sure, have you pressed/toggled the WPS button on the router when the Android device is asking for the password?

Comment: WPS is an insecure technology (too many flows in it's design) and therefore should be disabled in all Wifi components where it is available. On some attacks an attacker can get the PIN within seconds.

Comment: @AndrewT. I added more info, thank you!

Comment: @Robert I know WPS is almost deprecated because it's not the most secure way to connect to WiFi but it's still implemented in some of the newest routers and I want to tested, so the security point is not the points here :)